# See who logged in to their Facebook account on my computer

Tags: google-chrome, history, facebook

Somebody has been on Facebook on my computer, and I would really like to find out who that person is. I see in my history that they logged me out my Facebook account, and logged again, presumably on their own.

This account they logged in to I would really like to find out. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You can install a keylogger on your computer and see whose credentials are entered. Can you click on the other person's Facebook links and see if you can recognize whose profiles they were viewing? Why don't you lock your computer? Is this a family PC? If you didn't have some sort of tracking implemented before the person did this then your best bet is to just secure your computer to prevent future problems.

Comment: http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/web_browser_password.html  :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you go to your browsers history scan down til you find the point where they logged you out and logged in. The page right after will be their profile. Because when you log in where do you go? To your home page.

Comment: It doesn't go to my profile page when I log into facebook.

Comment: It is automatic. When you hit the login button it sends you to your home page (profile). Not profile as in settings.